# iOS binding library for .NET MAUI

Tags: maui, maui-windows, maui-ios

I have a .NET MAUI app which needs to use native iOS and Android libraries. I created the Android binding library without any issue.

When trying to create the iOS binding library, However, after the binding library project to MAUI App, I found that the project structure is a bit different than Xamarin.Forms: There is no "Native Library" option under Frameworks (net8.0-ios).

Thus after some R&D, I had manually copy and paste some code in MAUI Proj file. Screen shot attached.

After all this affords, ***My Code works fine in MAC Machine But iOS project doesnot work in Windows Environments.***

Please someone guide which addition configuration/code I have to write to resolve this issue? Any help is greatly appreciated! I use Visual Studio 2022 Latest update Nov-2023.

Some Screen shots attached as reference.

**Error**

[image]

[image]

[image: iOS Code]

Comment: I have had this problem before. First of all don't reference the framework in maui csproj, that's what the binding library is here for. Second, remove the binding library project reference from your tester, and instead reference the dll file.
The dll file is the build product of your binding library and sits in the "bin\Debug\net7.0-ios" folder.

Comment: @o_w : Tried but not working in Windows Environment. It would be great for me if you share some useful blogs links or url of sample code. Waiting for your reply

Comment: It didn't work for me in Windows environment because of the difference between VS2022 and VS For Mac. I had to edit tester project's csproj project and dll references to be conditional as well, according to which target I'm building for(Android/iOS). That way I only worked on iOS on the Mac, and for Android on Windows.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your response.